# onEndReached not called when new data on same page

Tags: react-native

So when I first load my component it fetches data from the server. The data is displayed and takes up less space than the screen. Shouldn't onEndReached be called in this situation? Or is my assumption incorrect because the data wasn't scrolled to? From my testing, onEndReached is not called on Android & IOS but I want it to.

```
    
/**
 * https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/typescript
 */
type Props = {
    navigation: NavigationDrawerProp<{ userId: string, routeName: string }>;
}

let idCounter = 0;

export const keyExtractor = (item: any) => {
    if (!item.uniqueId) {
        item.uniqueId = idCounter;
        idCounter++;
    }

    return item.uniqueId.toString();
}

const MasterScreen = (props: Props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const loadDataFirstTime = () => {


        setTimeout(() => {
            let newData = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                newData.push({})
            }
            setData(newData)
        }, 4000)


    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadDataFirstTime();
    }, []);

    const renderItem = () => {
        return <Text>Placeholder</Text>
    }

    const onEndReached = () => {
        console.log("End reached with data length", data.length)
        Alert.alert("Data length: " + data.length)
    }


    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, height: height }}>
            <FlatList data={data}
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                onEndReached={onEndReached}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}


            />
        </SafeAreaView>

    );

}
```

Using react native 0.63.4

EDIT:
[Sample github repo](https://github.com/joshua-augustinus/training-flatlist-end)

- Relevant code inside src/screens/MasterScreen.tsx
- onEndReached is not called on load but you will see the FlatList rendered
- To test:

```
yarn
yarn android
```

Comment: It should be triggered on load, could you try and create a minimum example where the alert is not triggered? : https://snack.expo.io/@nipuna777/flatlist-example

Comment: Updated original post with github minimal sample repo

Comment: The only problem for the methods of the virtualized Lists is, that if it is nested inside another Virtualized List or ScrollView these methods will not be triggered. If you have any ScrollView or another FlatList in the Parent components this should be the problem otherwise there is no sense that this method is not triggered.